# Symfony Bundle name for overriding files

Tags: php, fosuserbundle, symfony

When extending/overriding a Bundle in a Symfony (3.0.x) project one adds the according folder to the "/app/Resources" folder. I got that.
What I did not get is how you know which name that folder should have.

Example:
The FOSUserBundle wants a folder named "FOSUserBundle".
The location of the bundle is "/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/".

Obviously this is not the same name as the folder in the app/Resources location gets.

Where do I find the name or mapping information of a bundle that defines how to call the folder to be added?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bundle name is the short class name (the final part of the class name without the namespace) of the actual bundle class (see [the code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Bundle/Bundle.php#L138-L153)).

A few examples..

```
FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle                  -> FOSUserBundle
Sylius\Bundle\ReviewBundle\SyliusReviewBundle -> SyliusReviewBundle
Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle          -> SonataBlockBundle
```

If you look at the class you use to add a bundle to your registered bundles you can get the bundle name from that.

So, for example (taken from the Sonata Block Bundle docs)..

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    return array(
        // Dependency (check that you don't already have this line)
        new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),

        // Vendor specifics bundles
        new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
        new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
    );
}
```

would be `KnpMenuBundle`, `SonataCoreBundle` and `SonataBlockBundle`.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally you can just execute the console command `config:dump-reference` to list the available bundle names.

3.x `php bin/console config:dump-reference`

~2.4 `php app/console config:dump-reference`

Outputs:

```
Available registered bundles with their extension alias if available:

+------------------------------+--------------------------+
| Bundle name                  | Extension alias          |
+------------------------------+--------------------------+
| AppBundle                    |                          |
| AsseticBundle                | assetic                  |
| DebugBundle                  | debug                    |
| DoctrineBundle               | doctrine                 |
| DoctrineMongoDBBundle        | doctrine_mongodb         |
| FrameworkBundle              | framework                |
| KnpMenuBundle                | knp_menu                 |
| KnpPaginatorBundle           | knp_paginator            |
| LiipImagineBundle            | liip_imagine             |
| MewesKTwigExcelBundle        | mewes_k_twig_excel       |
| MonologBundle                | monolog                  |
| SecurityBundle               | security                 |
| SensioDistributionBundle     | sensio_distribution      |
| SensioFrameworkExtraBundle   | sensio_framework_extra   |
| SensioGeneratorBundle        |                          |
| StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle | stof_doctrine_extensions |
| SwiftmailerBundle            | swiftmailer              |
| TwigBundle                   | twig                     |
| UserBundle                   |                          |
| VichUploaderBundle           | vich_uploader            |
| WebProfilerBundle            | web_profiler             |
+------------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You cand find the bundle name in the main php Class of any bundle, it is called like the bundle, in this case in /vendor/friendofsymfony/user-bundle/FOSUserBundle